# How to serve two different html pages to mobile and desktop devices

Tags: php, html, css

I have looked a bit here, but could only find solution for wordpress or similar.

I have a rather minimal website that features two entirely different approaches for mobile and desktop users.

Ideally, I would like to serve two completely different websites to these two categories of users. Less ideally, I would settle for serving two different landing pages to the two users.

How can I achieve this? Either php, or javascript, or any other solution would do, as long as it is fully working (i.e. I can reproduce it from here without going too crazy with learning new things). The simpler the better as I am not the most skilled in web development (and that's fine, this is a minor artsy project that I'm doing for fun).

EDIT:

An attempt using jquery and the code suggested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MyPage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div id="mobile-container">
mobile
    </div>

    <div id="desktop-container">
        desktop
    </div>
    <!-- This script switches based on the detected screen-->

    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      jQuery('#mobile-container').show();
    }else{
      jQuery('#desktop-container').show();
   }
});
    </script>


</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Are they so completely different (and if so, why) that you can't just use Responsive Design techniques with HTML and CSS? You could at the very least use media queries simply to serve up two totally different sets of HTML depending on the detected viewport size. P.S. Just FYI you can't really do anything for this in PHP, since it's running on the server and has no idea of how the page will be displayed on the client - it simply returns some HTML to the requesting client. It doesn't even know for sure whether the requester is even a web browser (as opposed to a bot or other type of program).

Comment: People used subdomains as `m.mysite.com` for mobile devices long time ago. Than one would be offered to switch the layout to desktop/mobile mode... But I would not recommend it, since it is a minimal website - so simply go wrap all your desktop and mobile code in separate containers and just use css media queries.

Comment: @ADyson yes, they are two completely different thing. The mobile website is a one-button, full screen thing. The desktop site fakes (or will fake) a terminal, to give a retro feel that is important to the project for reasons. So they have different content.

Comment: well you can either attempt to detect user-agent strings on the server to serve up different content - but as I alluded to earlier, this isn't particularly reliable, they can also be spoofed, and also it doesn't detect the exact viewport size, it can only (attempt) to distinguish between "mobile" and "desktop" browsers. So the idea which two of us have suggested with separate media queries is probably a better one.

Comment: I see, it looks like media queries is the way to go, but could I ask for a minimal working example that I can tweak to fit my page?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/ is probably a good place to start. There are plenty of other similar examples online too. Your different stylesheets should, at minimum, contain rules which show and hide the relevant sections of HTML depending on the screen size

Answer (score 0):

You should use two different container with different html  according to  desktop or mobile view. By default make both container display:none

Then use jquery for change the view.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
       Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      jQuery('#mobile-conatiner').show();

    }else{
      jQuery('#desktop-conatiner').show();
   }
});
```